# Cherrypy 3.2 virtual host dispatcher

Tags: python, python-3.x, cherrypy, virtualhost

i am trying to get virtual host working in cherrypy 3.2.0 runing on python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cherrypy
from cherrypy import expose

class Root(object):

    @expose
    def index(self):
        return "I am the root  vhost"

class Foo(object):

    @expose
    def index(self):
        return "I am testingdomain.com"

class Bar(object):

    @expose
    def index(self):
        return "I am testingdomain2.com."

def main():

    cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': 'rootdomain.com',
            'server.socket_port': 80,
    })

    conf = {
        "/": {
            "request.dispatch": cherrypy.dispatch.VirtualHost(
            **{
                "testingdomain.com:8000": "/foo",
                "testingdomain2.com:8000": "/bar"
            })
        }
    }

    root = Root()
    root.foo = Foo()
    root.bar = Bar()
    cherrypy.tree.mount(root, "", conf)

    #cherrypy.quickstart()
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have got testing domains enlisted in /etc/hosts. When requesting, they are correctly directed to server.
But the only page i got served is Root even if I go to testingdomain.com or testingdomain2.com.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: you're telling cherrypy to serve on port 80 with the 'server.socket_port' option, but your vhosts all have ports of 8000...

Comment: I really hoped, that that was the problem. I changed vhosts ports to 80, but nothing changed. I am still getting the Root page on all testing domains. Any other ideas?

Comment: should there be a port at all in the vhost description?

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Yes! It is working now. I removed vhosts ports and it is working. Weird, because documentation example uses ports with vhosts. http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/VirtualHosts Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ports that they show in the cherrypy docs are values other than '80'.  `curl` at least, does not add port numbers to the `Host` request header if the port is 80;  I suspect that `cherrypy.dispatch.VirtualHost` is not clever enough to match a host header of `example.com` on port 80 to `example.com:80` or visa versa.  I would probably map both hosts (with and without port numbers )in the config in case an unusual host header happens to come down the wire.